Is it is not good to instantiate the dbContext in my repository when I am trying you independency injection?
I would like to create a repository for queries. For that, I was thinking of doing something like this:
public interface ICarsQueryRepository
{
    public GetCarById(long Id);

    //Another methods of repository.
}



public class CarsQueryRepositorySqlServerEntityCore8: ICarsQueryRepository
{
    private readonly ContextoConsultasPedidosCompras _context;



    //I inject IGetConnectionString to get the connection string, so I can create the dbContext here.
    public CarsQueryRepositorySqlServerEntityCore8(IGetConnectionString paramConnectionString)
    {
        //La configuarción que tendrá el dbContext
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<CarsContext> miBulider = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CarsContext>();

        miBulider.UseSqlServer(paramConnectionString);

        _contexto = new CarsContext(miBulider.Options);
    }



    public GetCarById(long paramId)
    {
        //do something using _context.
    }
}

Here, I am creating the dbContext in the constructor of the repository.
Normally, it is recommended not to create resources in the same class. It is better to inject them, mainly for two reasons: lower coupling, because I can change the implementation, and easier testing.
Regarding coupling, I think a repository is tied to a version of the dbContext. So, if I want to test the repository, I want to test if it works with this dbContext. I will not have tests that use mocks for another implementation. If I want to use another version of the dbContext, I would implement another repository, because there would be changes that break compatibility.
I think it is the consumer of the repository who needs to be injected with the interface of the repository to be able to use it.
I think that in this way, I have the benefit that the consumer doesn’t need to know the implementation of the repository. It doesn’t matter if the repository uses Entity Core, ADO.NET, or another technology.
I mention this because, in many code examples, I have seen the main application register the dbContext as a dependency to be injected into the repository. I think this increases the coupling, as I am coupling the main application to a specific version of the dbContext. Additionally, this makes the main application aware of the repository’s implementation, which raises the question: why?
In summary, I am wondering if it is really a bad idea to create the dbContext in the repository instead of registering the dbContext in the dependency injection manager to inject it into the repository.
Thanks.

I think this increases the coupling, as I am coupling the main application to a specific version of the dbContext
There are some edge cases but usually it is not a problem  - your "main application" is the composition root and it is ok for it to actually know all the dependencies to perform the DI:

The composition root is the single place in your application where the composition of the object graphs for your application takes place


A Composition Root is a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together.
Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn't.
A DI Container should only be referenced from the Composition Root. All other modules should have no reference to the container.

Additionally, this makes the main application aware of the repository’s implementation, which raises the question: why?
The answer is the same - "main application" is the composition root.
I am wondering if it is really a bad idea to create the dbContext in the repository instead of registering the dbContext in the dependency injection manager to inject it into the repository.
Usually concrete applications are quite homogeneous in terms of DAL technologies used, usually you will work with the same ORM (if any) and with the same database type, your current setup can make quite a headache to change the  wire up of the context for multiple repositories (and usually you will share context type between repos), this can be worked around with some helper methods but why bother when you can just inject it.
Also the "user" still need to know the implementation details of the repository - due to EF Core usage and how it is working with DML operations (and DAL operations by default - via tracking) repositories should be registered as scoped (otherwise it can lead to different problems). This can be handled in multiple ways (clearing change tracker manually, creating contexts per operation/DB request) but personally I don't see much benefit here.
Note that using DI to inject DbContext's does not limit a concrete repository to using it - some repos can use the another DbContext type or no DbContext's at all.
Regarding coupling, I think a repository is tied to a version of the dbContext. So, if I want to test the repository, I want to test if it works with this dbContext.
While ideally yes, it is better to use the same setup for repository testing as the app will use, but it is not always feasible/easy, injecting DbContext will actually allow you to perform unit testing over some other DB type compared to one used in production. For example I had some "smoke" unit testing via SQLite when another DB type was used in production (obviously it has not covered all potential problems but some were caught on this level before going to integration testing). Ideally though you might want to use some test containers and spin up "correct" DB type to test against - but still you might want to have different setup in terms of logging, etc. which would be possible with DI.

@AndrewMorton changed to italics. Though still prefer headers a bit)

I have another question. Supose that I want to follow the CQRS pattern, in which I have one repository for queries and one repository for commands. In this case I have I would have two dbContexts. Should I have a ApplicationContextCommands and a ApplicationContextQueries and register both in the DI Container?

@ÁlvaroGarcía do you have different databases for reads and writes? Do they have the same schema?


I think that in this way, I have the benefit that the consumer doesn’t need to know the implementation of the repository. It doesn’t matter if the repository uses Entity Core, ADO.NET, or another technology.

If implemented in the opposite way, where the DbContext is injected into the repository, this also holds.
The consumer has the repository injected. The repository has the DbContext injected.
The consumer doesn't know anything about the DbContext. The DI container does.

I think this increases the coupling, as I am coupling the main application to a specific version of the dbContext.

That's what the Composition Root is for - to be the only place to know all concrete types. There's no increased coupling, no other place in your code is coupled to the DbContext.

In summary, I am wondering if it is really a bad idea to create the dbContext in the repository instead of registering the dbContext in the dependency injection manager to inject it into the repository.

You gave two reasons for injecting DbContext into the repository:

lower coupling
easier testing

You forgot the lifetime.
Often, there are multiple repositories that span only specific domain contexts but it's a common practice to have a DbContext that is wider, contains tables from multiple repositories.
You then have a Unit of Work that is just a composition of multiple repositories.
But then, having multiple repositories raises an important issue: if multiple repositories are instantiated in the very same lifetime span (e.g. a web request) should you have multiple different DbContext instantiated in different repositories in the very same lifetime span?
No.
This is against what DbContext is for - it should preferably be reused in the same lifetime span, for example because of its First Level Cache (and possibly other features). This is why you usually register your DbContext as scoped.
By injecting the very same DbContext into multiple repositories in the very same lifetime span, you ensure that DbContext is used in an optimal way.
And still, if for any reason, you need a separated DbContext in the very same lifetime span, you can do it (you just don't rely on the DI container's default registration).
The consumer doesn't know anything about the DbContext, as it's the DI container that resolves the DbContext, injected into the repository.
